# executei o comando git pull e o meu branch e o branch da faculdade divergiram-se

Tags: git, github, terminal

Eu executei o comando git pull, confundindo-me com git push para submeter as atividades no servidor da faculdade, e agora o meu branch e o da faculdade (origin/master) divergiram, o que fazer? Abaixo esta a mensagem completa

No ramo master
o seu branch e "origin/master" divergiram-se,
e cada um tem 1 de 1 submissões, respectivamente.
(use "git pull" to merge the branch into yours)
Todos os conflitos foram corrigidos mas você continua mesclando
(use "git commit" para concluir a mesclagem)

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

quando você fez o Pull, ele baixou os arquivos que estavam na branch e não estavam no seu pc, se ele precisou resolver conflitos, é possível que vc precisasse fazer isso de uma forma ou de outra.
Agora que os conflitos foram resolvidos, no caso, as alterações de ambas as partes estão incluídas, vc precisa criar o commit e ai sim fazer o push.

Porem teste bem antes de fazer o push, pois durante essas correções de conflito, algo pode ter saído errado